# Need help converting this string from Python 2 to Python 3 {print >>f,timestamp,"\t",int(time.time()),"\t",Data}

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python 3 and having issues converting this line from Python 2 to 3, any experts here that could help? Thank you!!

```
print >>f,timestamp,"\t",int(time.time()),"\t",Data
```

Comment: reading a documentation of python3 would be great if you want to learn python3 
`print(f,timestamp,"\t",...)`

Comment: Also consider using something like [2to3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html).

Comment: Also sidenote @Tserenjamts I think OP is going for a file write instead of trying to print out the variable "f".

Comment: `print >>f, ...` is `print(..., file=f)`.